# How to compress files in google drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, compression, google-drive-api

Is there any way to compress large files into smaller .zip of .tar.gz files in google drive? I tried google [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259041/creating-a-zip-file-inside-google-drive-with-apps-script) but it created .zip files but not compressing. How to do this?

Answer (score 26):

I found there is an efficient, fast, simple but indirect method of zipping/unzipping the large files into Google Drive using [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb).

For example,
Let us assume there is a directory named **Dataset** of size 5 GB in your Google Drive, the task is to zip (compress) it to **Dataset.zip**.

Google Drive:

> My Drive
>
> > Dataset

Steps:

1. Open [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb) (it's free), Create a **New Notebook**.
2. Mount Google drive into Google Colab by running the following command lines:

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Note: Now on the left side (Files) you can observe your **My Drive** inside **gdrive** and folder **Dataset** inside **My Drive**.

Screenshot before zipping.

[Colab Drive Mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7toa.png)

3. Change the current directory by following command run.

   `cd gdrive/My Drive/`
4. Zip files/folder: **Dataset** to **Dataset.zip** using the following command run.

   `!zip -r Dataset.zip Dataset/`

Screenshots after zipping:

[Colab Drive Mount after zipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzfh8.png)

[Google Drive Screenshot after zipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec0bu.png)

Note: The above commands are inspired by ubuntu. Hence, for unzipping use:

`!unzip filename.zip -d ./filename`

Comment: Very useful, thanks ! For me, the above only worked with gzip though (which is fine)

Answer (score 3):

I have tried and tested the below code with a pdf file which is in my Drive of 10MB size and it did compressed it for 9MB. I even tested for a Drive file(slides), it did compress it.

```
function fileZip(){
 var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Google_Apps_Script_Second_Edition.pdf');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
 file = file.getBlob()}

DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.zip([file], 'tutorialFiles.zip'));

}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: expecting like 6 MB or 7 MB of conversion of your file . Is that possible ?

Comment: Rather depends on the file-type. We uses some proprietary files that occasionally are larger zipped than unzipped. It all depends o how compact the data type is and how well it suits a particular compression algorithm. No idea which zip schema GAS uses.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's even easier than that. Files are already Blobs (anything that has getBlob() can be passed in to any function that expects Blobs). So the code looks like this:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('path/to/folder');
folder.createFile(Utilities.zip(folder.getFiles(), 'newFiles.zip'));
```

Additionally, it won't work if you have multiple files with the same name in the Folder... Google Drive folders support that, but Zip files do not.

To make this work with multiple files that have the same name:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('path/to/folder');
var names = {};
folder.createFile(Utilities.zip(folder.getFiles().map(function(f){
  var n = f.getName();
  while (names[n]) { n = '_' + n }
  names[n] = true;
  return f.getBlob().setName(n);
}), 'newFiles.zip'));
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259041/creating-a-zip-file-inside-google-drive-with-apps-script))